# Why are deployment JARs packaged in production Quarkus app?

Tags: quarkus

A vulnerability scan highlighted the presence of Maven JARs in the Docker image for our Quarkus app which surprised me. These are being picked up from `quarkus-app/lib/main`. Running `mvn quarkus:dependency-tree` shows the route by which they're getting included:

```
[INFO] --- quarkus-maven-plugin:2.2.3.Final:dependency-tree (default-cli) @ my-app ---
[INFO] Quarkus application PROD mode build dependency tree:
[INFO] my-group:my-app:pom:1.x-SNAPSHOT
...
[INFO] ├─ io.quarkus:quarkus-undertow-deployment:jar:2.2.3.Final (compile)
...
[INFO] │  ├─ io.quarkus:quarkus-core-deployment:jar:2.2.3.Final (compile)
...
[INFO] │  │  ├─ io.quarkus:quarkus-bootstrap-core:jar:2.2.3.Final (compile)
...
[INFO] │  │  │  ├─ io.quarkus:quarkus-bootstrap-maven-resolver:jar:2.2.3.Final (compile)
[INFO] │  │  │  │  ├─ org.apache.maven:maven-embedder:jar:3.8.1 (compile)
```

Again, I was surprised to see that it was pulling in deployment JARs as, based on my limited understanding, I would have not expected these to be needed at runtime for a non-mutable production app.

EDIT: The POM just references the extension and then there is a parent POM that references the Quarkus BOM.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-undertow</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

If the deployment JARs are needed, why, and, if not, is there a way to exclude them?

Comment: The `dependency:tree` output looks like the `my-app` module itself declares a dependency on the `quarkus-undertow-deployment` artifact. If so, that's a mistake.

Comment: Show your Maven or Gradle file.

Comment: @Ladicek - the POM just references the extension, not the deployment artifact directly. This is part of a production app (just renamed for inclusion here) but I can try a simpler recreate that I can share if that would help?

Comment: A small reproducer would certainly be good to have -- you might find a problem on your side while preparing it, or it will be useful for reporting a possible bug.

Answer (score 0):

As @Ladicek suggested, the cause of this issue was that one of dependencies was referencing the deployment artifact directly (just not the one I posted in the question!). This was then causing the deployment JARs for all of the extensions to be packaged in `quarkus-app/lib/main`.

Correcting `quarkus-logging-json-deployment` to `quarkus-logging-json` fixed the problem.